# ffmpeg.exe not working when 3gp file converting flv

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert 3gp file to flv. Below is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Working Projects\B2CJewelsLive\images\TestimonialVideo\smaller.3gp" \
-vb 700000 -ar 22050 -ab 56 -r 24 -f flv -sameq -s 430x254 \
"D:Images\TestimonialVideo\\smaller_134.flv"
```

Answer (score 1):

The command works for me if I replace *-sameq* with *-qscale 0*. Also, you have a typo in your destination address (backslash after "D:" is missing). Plus, make sure you are using the newest version of ffmpeg and the 3gp file isn't corrupt.